# Site names are multi-lined in the footer

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, footer

There is an alignment issue in the footer of all the Stack Exchange sites (except Stack Overflow). The site names under the **OTHER** section are multi-lined.

It was fine before some time, reference in the [Web Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20170628160727/https://meta.stackexchange.com/). Puzzling was added under the **CULTURE/RECREATION** section that may caused the issue.

[image: Text in the footer is multi-lined]

Comment: Not really relevant, in 6-8 weeks the footer on all sites will be the same as it is now on Stack Overflow.

Comment: On [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/#footer), it's even more awkward because of the diagram in the footer.

Comment: @Glorfindel Reported a bug for the [new footer change](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8616/276937)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Shadow already mentions in the comments, we recently released a new footer on Stack Overflow that drastically simplifies the footer and makes this issue obsolete. There's no definitive timeline on when that will make its way to the rest of the network, but sooner rather than later is a good bet, and it doesn't make sense to continue to fix issues like this in a footer that will disappear soon. These kinds of issues are why we designed a new footer, after all.